# DICOM file generated does not open

Tags: fo-dicom

DICOM file generated on SCP print does not open! I'm just trying to save an image in DICOM format. I tried in many ways. Thanks for the contribution!
fo-dicom 4.0.7

```
            string receivingFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "PrintJobs");
            string dir = Path.Combine(receivingFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyddMM HHmmss"));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

            DicomFile file;
            foreach (var box in filmSession.BasicFilmBoxes)
            {

                file = new DicomFile(box);
                string filename = Path.Combine(dir, box.SOPInstanceUID.UID);
                
                file.Save(Path.Combine(filename));
                
                file.Save(Path.Combine(filename + "test2.dcm"));

                var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings
                {
                    PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer",
                    PrintToFile = true,
                    PrintFileName = Path.Combine(dir, box.SOPInstanceUID.UID + "-test3.dcm")
                };
                printDocument = new PrintDocument
                {
                    PrinterSettings = printerSettings,
                    DocumentName = box.SOPInstanceUID.UID,
                    PrintController = new StandardPrintController()
                };
                printDocument.Print();
                printDocument.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: A Dicom Printjob has a hierachy. Highes level is a PrintSession (a job). this contains of several FilmBoxes (pages in the job). a FilmBox then has some ImageBoxes (images on the page) and those then again do have a ImageSequence (mostly one image but can be several images). So a printjob is organized completely different from a classical DICOM-file with the PixelData attribute etc. The file you are saving here is a valid DICOM-file, but no dicomviewer will show you the images as you would expect. Try running a StoreSCP instead of a PrintSCP to get the images.

Comment: @gofal3 Thanks for helping. I will do this!